# deserialize json into my C# object gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jsonserializer

I get such JSON and want to deserialize it into my C# object. But this ends up in an error that cannot deserialize. Can I get help in fixing this?

```
 public class UserDto {
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<string> Permissions { get; set; }
 }
```

Above is the model object for binding the API output

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"/users");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode || response.Content == null) {
  return null;
}
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

UserDto users = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<UserDto>();

List<UserDto> x2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserDto>>(result);
```

The above `getasync` method gives me the below result and i am trying to deserialize it to object.

```json
{
    "users": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ttest",
        "permissions": [
            "add",
            "edit",
            "delete"
        ]
    }]
}
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) 
into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[****.Models.UserDto]' 
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) 
or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type 
(e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an
array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to 
deserialize from a JSON object.
```

I get such JSON and want to deserialize it into my C# object. But this ends up in an error that cannot deserialize. Can I get help in fixing this?

Comment: First of all, you can't read the content twice. If you want to read it both as string and as a JSON, you need to copy it to memory stream first. But I would suggest to drop the string altogether. Just read it as JSON from the start, you just need the correct DTO that corresponds to the JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON, `Users` JArray is inside a JObject, so to convert your JSON string you need `List<User>` inside a `RootObject` class like,

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize like,

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
```

[.NETFIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j6LHkk)